# i want to toggle one div after ajax call loads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am triggering a click event on one element. which in turn calls some function which has ajax calls in them. I want to toggle one div(which will get loaded after ajax call) after ajax call loads the page.

```
 function triggerFunction(){
     $("#trigger_div").trigger("click");
     $("#toggle_div").toggle(); //this div gets loaded after ajax call which happens after triggering click event
}
```

Comment: You need to post your AJAX call to. Either you use callbacks or promises or async/await?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery css() Method to update the css of any div in success callback of ajax.

Here is how you can make it work

```
$.ajax({ 
url: './AnotherPage.php',
success: function(output) {
    $("#toggle_div"). toggle();
    $("#toggle_div").css("css_property", "property_value"); 
    // $("#toggle_div").css("background_color", "red");
              }
            });
```

Recommend you to always use success and failure callback for Ajax .

Comment: But i dont have access to underline ajax call. I am just triggering one click event which in turn can have multiple ajax call.

Comment: cleanest way to do this i've mentioned already but in your case as you say you don't have access to success functions, Use something like this

function callAjaxfunc(callback) {
    //All ajax calls called here
    onAjaxSuccess: function() {
        callback();
    };
    $("#toggle_div"). toggle();
    $("#toggle_div").css("css_property", "property_value");   
}